# Best way to master Flutter

Tags: flutter

hope you're doing well, I'm totally new to mobile development with flutter and I kinda like it, and I want to build my profile and increase my knowledge in it.
what are your advices, currently using firebase database, any other database that is usually used in flutter, what projects to build to get more knowledge, besides ecommerce app, todo app.
I searched on the web, but wanted to listen and take advices from the experts on StackOverlflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn learn Flutter from Basic things.

> Refer Documentation for Flutter [here](https://flutter.dev/)
>
> Learn Dart language for it used for flutter [here](https://dart.dev/)
>
> If you used some packages and some dependency go [here](https://pub.dev/)
>
> Refer You tube channel for flutter community for Widgets [here](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjxrf2q8roU23XGwz3Km7sQZFTdB996iG)
>
> you can find number of Courses on you tube regarding flutter